# How can NodeJS scale an enterprise application?

Tags: node.js, architecture, software-design

Suppose I have an enterprise Java application that basically does the following:

gather user input, query the backend databases (maybe multiple), run some algorithm (say do some in-memory calculation of the queried data sets to produce some statistics etc.), then return the data in some html pages.

My question is: If the bottleneck of the application is on the db query, how can NodeJS helps me in this scenarios since I still need to do all those post-db algorithm before I render the page? How an application architecture looks like?

Comment: If the bottleneck is in the database, why would using a different application layer solve the problem?

Comment: Anything unclear here?  The answer below should hopefully clarify.

Answer (score 3):

Of course node can't speed up your storage layer and make that single request that's incurring so much backend processing satisfy that request any faster to the end user.  But what it can do is not tie up a thread in the application server thread pool.  The single thread can continue on it's loop while that work is going on and accept another request.

That other request might be a cheaper request that will return when it's work is done.  That can also happen in an application server with a thread pool model ... that is unless all the threads in the thread pool model are tied up blocked on I/O requests - along with the overhead of each thread.  The cheaper request will get queued waiting on a thread out of the thread pool because they are all blocking.  Nodes single thread would loop and server the cheap request.

This works because node mandates that all I/O is async and the only work that blocks the loop is your code.  That's why the saying "[everything in node runs in parallel except your code](http://blog.mixu.net/2011/02/01/understanding-the-node-js-event-loop/)".  While it's possible to write async code in other application servers and achieve similar results, many offer non-async thread pool models where the coding is easier but sometimes less scalable.

For example, [this hanselman post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx) illustrates how asp.net is capable of doing async requests but it's not the common model that most have used.

Comment: I understand "everything in node runs in parallel except your code" concept in NodeJS. However, my question is around "if for most requests my application have to do some sort of in-memory post processing (after retrieving the data from db, for example), then what my application architecture is going to be look like?  Writing all the in-memory post processing within Node? Or still having the multi-threaded front end like I have now and outsource only the data retrieving tasks to Node?

Comment: I think it's hard to come up with a canned response to post db processing.  Are you just updating some in memory data structures that are really fast (variables)?  Sure - you're blocking the loop but it's not I/O - you're just updating in-memory.  Is it more complicated processing and data strucutres that even need to possibly scale out?  Look at Redis, memcachedb, etc... They have async read/write.  BTW, state that fits in memory like you're describing is a good fit for Redis & node.  There's also other caching modules that are purely in memory.